# Ошибка: error writing to -: Invalid argument }

Tags: c++, qt

Ошибку выдает в main, без понятия что это может быть
Код мэйна:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "type.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

Код заголовочного type.h

```
#define NAME_SIZE 10
#define START_AR_SIZE 2
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QErrorMessage>
#pragma once

using namespace std;
```

Код mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

Версия Qt  4.2.1
Windows 10
Ошибку выдает на последней строке в мэйне

Comment: В какой момент выдает? На какую строку ссылается? Что такое `city`? Приведите код в соответствии [mcve], укажите ОС и версию Qt, то есть всё то, чтобы кто-то другой мог повторить проблему.

Comment: скорее всего в файле type.h есть синтаксичесая ошибка. Вот оно и вылазит.

Comment: Обратите внимание на слово "минимальный". В коде не стоит приводить всё то лишнее, что не влияет на проявление проблемы.

Comment: Однозначно не стоит писать *using namespace* в заголовочном файле. Ну и в представленном виде в main нет 24 строчки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена
Помог ответ на англоязычном стаке :
Check the *.pro file. This error can arise because qmake looks for not existing file at the end of the list after a symbol "\". Remove the last symbol "\".

For example maybe you have in pro-file:

```
HEADERS += file1.hpp \
   file2.hpp \
   file3.hpp \
```

You need to change the code as follows :

```
HEADERS += file1.hpp \
   file2.hpp \
   file3.hpp
```